# Any good free materials libraries online?

Tags: materials

I'm wondering if there's any addons or online libraries of materials I can download. I've found one called [`online_mat_lib`](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Material/Online_Material_Library), but then discovered it was from 2008 and thought by now something like that might already be integrated into Blender.

Comment: online_mat_lib is an addon available in addons_contrib, while not yet included with official releases it is included with most other builds. It's library is created by exporting cycles node setups to an xml file which can be added to the library or shared individually. [This BA thread](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?256334-An-Online-Material-Library-Add-on-Beta-Version-0-6!) has a more recent discussion.

Comment: @gandalf3 Definitely.

Comment: I found the site www.blender-materials.com that is working too, and has blender internal render materials that are more likely to be usable in game development (not BGE), but I cant find the license for their files in any place ..

Comment: @Gandalf3 +1 to All : feel free to read and feed [BSE ressources](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender) where you can find and share ressources for blender!

Answer (score 17):

Some resources:

- 600+ Materials at [Open Material Repository](http://matrep.parastudios.de/)
- Temporary offline (http://www.blender-materials.org/) backed up by the above.
- For textures [cgtexures](http://www.cgtextures.com/) and [3dartisty](http://www.3dartisty.com/) is a good resource.
- [BlenderKit](https://www.blenderkit.com/) add-on offers about 2600 free materials, both texture based and procedural. Requires an account.

Comment: open material repo is not usable, on entering, loads of php code shows up :(, the main still offline :(, and cgtextures has a very serious problem for game developers ["It is NOT permitted to: Sell or distribute any of these textures in an unmodified form, or where the derived product you are selling or distributing is a Texture or a collection of Textures. IN OTHER WORDS: Do not sell or distribute any of these textures (modified or not) by itself or in a texture, material, clipart, website theme or scrapbooking pack!"](http://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-227060.html) :( :( :(

Comment: I wonder if the openMatRepo could provide the files in ftp mode? would help a lot!

Comment: I would like to add that, like cgtextures, www.goodtextures.com have a similar problem ["do not redistribute or sell textures by themselves, or as texture packs, or as clipart, or as material packs, or as scrapbooking packs."](http://www.goodtextures.com/faq.html), concerning the way we pack the assets for a game.

Comment: It looks like Open Mat Repo is back up. However, the materials do not appear to be able to be read by blender 2.79.

Comment: BlenderKit has now over 3000 free materials. B.t.w. Account isn't needed;)

Answer (score 13):

For cycles you can find many materials in [Blendswap](http://www.blendswap.com/). Here you have some users who provide many materials, most of them procedural materials without images, just with node setups:

- [Elbrujodelatribu](http://www.blendswap.com/user/elbrujodelatribu) (me)
- [Moony](http://www.blendswap.com/user/moony)
- [Kaluura](http://www.blendswap.com/user/kaluura)
- And the Meta-Androcto library

You must be logged in to download.

[image: metals pack in blendswap]

Answer (score 10):

You may want to see this two things:

- [Cycles_Matlib](http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/56470), is a blend file with many materials. Requires an account at blendswap.
- [Matlibvx addon](https://sites.google.com/site/aleonserra/home/scripts/matlib-vx), is an addon that add a library (empty) to blender so you can store your on materials, etc.

The good thing is that Cycles_Matlib include files to support Matlibvx so you can use both. They are easy to install (only unzip in addons folder).

Also note that are materials for cycles. But it also have a old version that I think is for blender internal.

You can read more about Cycles_Matlib in [blenderartists.org thread](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?252957-Cycles_Matlib-Beta-Release!-Help-Wanted!).

This is a preview of materials in Cycles_Matlib:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Blendswap.com](http://www.blendswap.com) also has user submitted material setups and you can request custom ones as well.

Answer (score 3):

[blendermada.com](http://blendermada.com/) already has quite a few materials that you can use freely. There is also a blender plugin for it.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is also new service - [BlenderKit - free online material and model database](https://www.blenderkit.com/) with add-on which allows to add them into scene by simple drag & drop even without register and login.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[BIS](https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/bis-online-blender-material-storage/) - Blender add-on and material library with public storage. You can use shared materials, store your own, and share them with other community. An account is required.

Answer (score 0):

I use [CG Bookcase](https://cgbookcase.com). They offer lots of good quality CC0 materials as big as 4K and all the maps you may want. And the site is updated pretty often. I used Blendermada just once.