# Resources for Blender

Tags: documentation

Since asking for tutorials, videos, resources, links to other content or downloads is considered off topic here, this is a specifically created Community Wiki which gathers resources for Blender and it has been approved by the [Community](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/410/should-we-have-a-few-questions-on-resources-for-use-with-blender).

Just write in the appropriate answer/section. If you have concerns, questions, post a [meta](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/) question, so we don't clutter the comments, but you can link your meta question from the comments.

Questions regarding such resources are not allowed anymore, except for very specific and on topic requests (ask on [Meta](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/) if you're unsure about your question). Follow the instructions made in the question about how to post, what can be posted, etc.

**Learning**

- [Official Documentation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/30581/1853)
- [Blender Communities and forums](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender/32990#32990)
- [Blogs](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender/32990#32990)
- [Online courses](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15376/599)
- [Books](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/16104/599)

**Assets**

- [Materials](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15361/599) (also see: [Any good free materials libraries online?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5593/599))
- [Textures, HDR environment maps, and photos](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15358/599)
- [Models](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15360/599)
- Reference Images/Blueprints (also see: [Where are some places to get reference images for modeling?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5322/599))
- [Sounds](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15357/599)

**Tools**

- [Addons](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15356/599) (also see: [Resource for Blender addons?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1342/599))
- [External Tools](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15362/599)
- [Render engines](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15363/599)
- [Rendering services](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15365/599)

**Other**

- Special Interest ([Blender resources for architects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7657/599))
- [Themes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15401/599)
- [Mathematics](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender/135314#135314)

Also see the [beginner's reference](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/40/599).

Comment: Use sites like: http://www.slant.co to collect interested resources relating to a topic. asked here: http://www.slant.co/topics/1761/~what-are-the-best-online-resources-for-making-art-with-blender3d

Comment: @ideasman42 See http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/410/should-we-have-a-few-questions-on-resources-for-use-with-blender and http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17380369#17380369

Comment: @ideasman42 We discussed this on meta. Since every few weeks or so a question pops up about resources, we thought it best to just have ___one___ community compiled resource and be done with it. Other sites on se  have something like this. It's strictly blender and a wiki so anyone can contribute. We have one on meta but new users aren't familiar with se and might not be aware of it so we are porting it to the main site and adding new sources.

Comment: How about commercially published books? I suspect that there are a number of (new) users who do not live close to a bookstore which stocks many books on 3D software, and may not be sufficiently sophisticated to search the web.

Comment: How about blogs, like Ben Simonds' (<http://bensimonds.com/>)?

Comment: Really think these questions should be disallowed, asking for lists of links which will change fairly often is totally outside SE format.

Comment: @ideasman42 Discussion should happen on the [relevant meta](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/410/599).

Comment: While adding a couple of things to the list, and the answers, it occurred to me that the list in the question could be better organized. So I did it.

Comment: Good job on completeing the reorganization.

Comment: I think BlenderGuru does a great job in his tutrials don't you think his page http://www.blenderguru.com/ or his youtube channel  https://www.youtube.com/user/AndrewPPrice are good for learning?

Comment: sometimes users may get into a small bug or a missing feature (maybe even some simple usability setting/tool): can we add also resources to help users to report bugs and submit feature requests (ie: contact developers) here? Then we can point such users here. Even on the blender.org site is not that easy to find how (that's a shame on its own, imho)

Answer (score 52):

<sub>Every section listed alphabetically</sub>

### Textures

- [ambientCG](https://ambientCG.com) (formerly [CC0Textures](http://www.cc0textures.com)) CC0/Public domain license
- [Good Textures](http://www.goodtextures.com) Similar to CG textures, but with a more lenient license. **Registration required**
- [Lovetextures](http://www.lovetextures.com)
- [Mayang's Textures](http://mayang.com/textures)
- [nordicfx](http://www.nordicfx.net/?works=free-textures) non-commercial
- [OpenGameArt](http://opengameart.org/textures/all) CC-BY
- [Pixar 128 Library](https://community.renderman.pixar.com/article/114/library-pixar-one-twenty-eight.html) 128 textures with normal and height maps originally made by Pixar Studio in 1993 and updated in 2015, CC BY 4.0
- [PixPlant's Seed Images](http://www.pixplant.com/pixfinder.php) Various licenses
- [Plain Textures](http://www.plaintextures.com) **Registration required**
- [Poliigon](https://www.poliigon.com/) Paid registration required for high resolution versions; several high resolution free textures available
- [Poly Haven - Textures](https://polyhaven.com/textures) CC0
- [Share Textures](https://www.sharetextures.com/) Collection of CC0 textures
- [Subtle Patterns](http://subtlepatterns.com)
- [Textures.com](https://textures.com) (formerly CG Textures) License covers commercial use, but not open source software. **Registration required, free at low resolutions**
- [Textures.TheFree3DModels](http://textures.thefree3dmodels.com) Attribution required Noncommercial
- [Texturebits](http://texturebits.blogspot.com)
- [Texture lib](http://texturelib.com/) free for commercial and none commercial use, license is very lenient
- [Texture Mate](http://www.texturemate.com)
- [Texture Ninja](https://texture.ninja/) A collection of CC0 textures
- [texture pilot](http://www.texturepilot.com) **Registration required**
- [Texture X](http://www.texturex.com) Free high resolution textures.
- [Yethiel's Collection of Textures](https://yethiel.wordpress.com/cc0-textures/) Various textures collected by an individual with CC0 license
- [3dmd.net](http://www.3dmd.net)  Small library and no high resolution
- [3DTextures](https://3dtextures.me/)

---

### HDR/JPEG Skydome Images

- [Adaptive Samples](http://adaptivesamples.com/category/hdr-panos) CC-BY-SA.
- [Chocofur HDRs](https://store.chocofur.com/search/hdr) High quality paid HDRs; one free available [here](https://store.chocofur.com/free-hdr-map-01)
- [GiantCowFilms.com](http://giantcowfilms.com/category/hdrs/) CC0/Public Domain
- [HDRMAPS](https://hdrmaps.com/) 20K paid hdris and [10K Free CC0-BY hdris](https://hdrmaps.com/freebies/). [Free add-on](https://hdrmaps.com/hmtools/) to download all hdris as assets.
- [HDRI Hub](http://www.hdri-hub.com/free-samples) Free Samples
- [MrBluesummers](http://www.mrbluesummers.com/category/downloads/downloads-textures-materials) HDR lights.
- [NoEmotion HDRs](http://noemotionhdrs.net) High resolution HDRs; CC-BY-ND
- [nordicfx](http://www.nordicfx.net/?works=hdri) non-commercial
- [Open Footage](http://www.openfootage.net/?cat=15) CC-BY
- [Philo's Sky Collection](http://www.philohome.com/skycollec/skycollec.htm)
- [Poly Haven - HDRIs](https://polyhaven.com/hdris) CC0
- [sIBL hdrlabs](http://www.hdrlabs.com/sibl/archive.html) CC-BY-SA
- [0ptikz's skies](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?24038-Free-high-res-skymaps-(Massive-07-update!))

---

### Stock Photos

- [BucketListly](http://photos.bucketlistly.com/) CC-BY-NC
- [Foter](http://foter.com/) Various CC Licenses
- [FreeImages](http://www.freeimages.com/)
- [Image After](http://imageafter.com/)
- [Immediate Entourage](http://www.immediateentourage.com/) many masked images
- [Library of Congress](http://www.loc.gov/pictures/) Public Domain
- [MorgueFile](http://morguefile.com/)
- [openclipart](https://openclipart.org/)
- [OpenImages](http://www.openimages.eu/media)
- [Openverse](https://wordpress.org/openverse/) creative commons/ public domain images and audio assets.
- [Pexels](https://www.pexels.com/) CC0
- [Pixabay](http://www.pixabay.com/) free, but with some restrictions
- [Pond5](https://www.pond5.com/free) **Registration required**
- [PhotoPin](http://photopin.com/) Various CC Licenses
- [PublicDomainPictures](http://publicdomainpictures.net/) reduced resolution free, Public Domain
- [Pxhere](https://pxhere.com) Free stock photos
- [Stockvault](http://www.stockvault.net/) non-commercial
- [Rawpixel](https://www.rawpixel.com/) free for commercial
- [Unsplash](https://unsplash.com/) CC0
- [USDA](http://www.ars.usda.gov/News/docs.htm?docid=23559) Public Domain
- [US Navy](http://www.navy.mil/viewGallery.asp) Public Domain
- [Visible earth NASA](http://visibleearth.nasa.gov/) Public Domain
- [3dtotal](http://freetextures.3dtotal.com/index.php) some textures too

Answer (score 29):

### External Tools

- [AwesomeBump](https://github.com/kmkolasinski/AwesomeBump)  is a free and open source program written using Qt library designed to generate normal, height, specular or ambient occlusion, metallic, roughness textures from a single image.
- [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) is a free and open source program designed for photo retouching, image composition and image authoring.
- [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) - Panorama Photo Stitcher
- [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/) is a free and open source vector graphics editor.
- [JMC2OBJ](http://www.jmc2obj.net/) - Minecraft to .obj converter for makers of MC scenes.
- [Krita](https://krita.org/) is a free digital painting and illustration application.
- [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) is a free and open source program that can capture an area of your desktop and save it directly to .GIF, or its own native lossless .LCF file format. It is available for Windows and Mac only, but the Windows version works remarkably well on Linux, through Wine.
- [MB-Lab](https://mb-lab-community.github.io/MB-Lab.github.io) is a free and open source Blender addon that creates humanoid characters. It is based off the popular ManuelBastioniLAB and offers standard skeletons for animation, anthropological phenotypes library, clothing and hair, morphing parameters, Anime Characters, and facial expressions as shape keys.
- [MakeHuman](http://www.makehumancommunity.org/) is a free and open source software for creating realistic 3D human models and rigs. The add-on MPFB2 can be thought of as a reimplementation of MakeHuman as a Blender add-on.
- [Materialize](http://boundingboxsoftware.com/materialize/) Free and Open source tool for creating material layers from flat images. Diffuse -> Height, Diffuse -> Metallic, Diffuse -> Smoothness, Height -> Normal, Height + Diffuse -> Normal, Normal -> Edge, Normal -> Occlusion, Normal + Height -> Occlusion, Normal -> Height, Seamlessly tile your textures, Save and load in a variety of formats, Automate many processes with clipboard commands in xml format.
- [Meshroom](https://alicevision.org/#meshroom) is a free, open-source
  3D Reconstruction Software based on the AliceVision framework.
- [Peek](https://github.com/phw/peek#installation) is also a free and open source program that can capture and area of your desktop and save it directly to .GIF, which it is optimized for, or to .APNG, .WebM, or .MP4. It is made for Linux operating systems.
- [PureRef](https://www.pureref.com/) is a simple and lightweight freeware tool for artists to organize and view their reference images. It is available for Windows, Mac or Linux.
- [Daz 3D](https://www.daz3d.com/) The standalone free software can export human models to Blender file format. It also has a paid store of assets for figures like clothing.

Answer (score 28):

### External Render engines:

- [LuxCoreRender](https://luxcorerender.org/)  (formerly [LuxRender](http://luxrender.net/)) is a physically based and unbiased rendering engine. Supports Blender integration.
- [Yafaray](http://www.yafaray.org/) is a free open-source raytracing engine which supports both biased an unbiased rendering methods. Supports Blender integration.
- [TheBounty](https://www.thebountyrenderer.org/) is a [free](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html) montecarlo raytracing engine. (fork of [Yafaray](http://www.yafaray.org/))
- [Mitsuba](http://www.mitsuba-renderer.org/) is a research-oriented rendering system in the style of PBRT.
- [Appleseed](http://appleseedhq.net/) is a modern, open source, physically-based renderer designed for production rendering.
- [Jot](http://jot.cs.princeton.edu/) is a program that lets designers, artists and animators directly annotate 3D computer graphics models (and animation) for stylized (NPR) rendering [in real time].

  *A blender exporter and more up to date info can be found [here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Render/Jot_Exporter_for_Blender).*
- [Nox](http://www.evermotion.org/nox) is a free stand-alone, physically-accurate state-of-an-art renderer. *Windows only*
  *(open-source since 2014 but seems original authors abandoned)*.
- [Aqsis](http://sourceforge.net/projects/aqsis/) is a cross-platform 3D rendering solution adhering to the RenderMan standard.
- [POV-ray](http://povray.org) is a high-quality, Free Software tool for creating stunning three-dimensional graphics. Supports Blender integration.
- [PRMan](https://github.com/bsavery/PRMan-for-Blender) Another cross platform integration of Pixar's RendermanProServer 20.0+ (Free for non-commercial use).
- [V-Ray for Blender](http://www.chaosgroup.com/en/2/vray_blender.html) An add-on that packages a .blend file and converts it into a format that V-Ray standalone knows how to render.
- [B-Maxwell](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bmaxwell/)
  The B-Maxwell add-on is a basic exporter from Blender to Maxwell Render (Windows and Linux). *"B-Maxwell add-on offers seamless integration with Maxwell Render and Blender"*
- [Octane-Render](https://home.otoy.com/render/octane-render/) Commercial plugin for blender available. GPU accelerated Unbiased rendering engine.

Answer (score 23):

### Rendering services:

- [rentaflop](https://rentaflop.com) fast and affordable crowdsourced rendering.
- [Sheep-it](https://www.sheepit-renderfarm.com/index.php) is a free distributed render farm for Blender.
- [Ray Pump](http://raypump.com/) *Closed down in 2016* is a software that provides free, easy and efficient access to GPU/CPU Render Farm. Current version is designed for Blender and its Cycles engine.
- [Blender Grid](http://blendergrid.com/)
- [RenderStreet](https://render.st/) (highly recommended among blender users)
- [Renderfarm.fi](http://www.renderfarm.fi/) (seems to be defunct, doesn't load)
- [Fox Renderfarm](https://www.foxrenderfarm.com/) offers free 25 credits for new one
- [Garage Farm](http://garagefarm.net/?lang=en)
- [Rendicity](http://www.rendicity.com/)
- [Keyframez](https://keyframez.com)
- [VFXFarm](https://vfxfarm.com) Fast Cloud Rendering Service Supports Major Plugins Maya, Octane, Blender, Houdini.

Answer (score 21):

### Models

- [Blendswap](http://www.blendswap.com/)
- [Blender models](http://www.blender-models.com/)
- [BlenderKit add-on](http://www.blenderkit.com/) (for 2.8, commercial but with some free stuff)
- [Blender for Architecture](http://blender-archi.tuxfamily.org/Models)
- [Chocofur](https://store.chocofur.com) Wide variety of high quality blend files made for Cycles and Blender; freebies at [this location](https://store.chocofur.com/search/free)
- [Noob to Pro](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Sources_of_free_3D_models) (list of resources)
- [Sketchfab Downloadables](https://sketchfab.com/features/download) Large collection; large variety; various licenses; blend files are far and few in between but formats that Blender can't import are rare too
- [TurboSquid](https://www.turbosquid.com/) Registration required; large collection of free stuff; blend files rare
- [PolyHaven](https://polyhaven.com/models) Expanding library of high quality models as blend and fbx files

Comment: Is it okay if I bring all the websites list from Noob to Pro book? The interface there is kinda hard on the eye.

Comment: @groundjet hm.. If you want, but maybe put them in a separate "noob to pro" answer and note the date, in case the list changes in the future.

Answer (score 21):

### Materials

- [Blendermada](http://blendermada.com/)
- [Blender-materials.org](http://www.blender-materials.org/) (currently in development. <s>In the meantime the old repo can be found [here](http://matrep.parastudios.de/)</s> It appears the old site is currently broken as well)
- [BlenderKit](https://www.blenderkit.com/) since blender 2.8 directly in Blender. more than 2600 materials
- [Cycles Material Vault](https://www.cyclesmaterialvault.com/) Paid; free sample download available from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4mrsiys6qs4hzm7/cycles_material_vault-freebies.zip?dl=0)

Comment: I cant find the license in absolutely any place for the materials downloadable from blender-materials.com, any idea?

Comment: @AquariusPower No idea. You could try contacting them (perhaps via their twitter? I don't see an email address..). I don't see much recent activity either.

Comment: A pity, their site is working really well (search/download), but I cant be sure when using those files :(. I found their google+ account and an email there at info icon. thx!

Comment: oh, but anyway, as my goal is model for games, and blender-materials.com had some compatible (not cycles), I was interested, but I just found out that we can bake cycles materials into textures, so may be I just give up on it :)

Comment: @ gandalf3 blender-material.org website not working?

Comment: @gandalf3 like material are there any lights material (warm light, volumetric light, soft light) we can import and directly apply like materials. i want to apply light on the surface. im making lantern and i want to have warm light, light glowing or light getting imitating from the mesh. any website for glowing light like material u have mention  above

Answer (score 19):

### Addons

- [Official Addons Catalog](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts)
- [Blender Addon List](http://blenderaddonlist.blogspot.de/)
- [Community addons featured on Blendernation](http://www.blendernation.com/category/blender/add-ons/)
- [BlenderArtists](http://blenderartists.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?48-Released-Scripts-and-Themes)
- [Blender Market](http://cgcookiemarkets.com/blender/all-products/category/scripts-and-addons/) (non-free)
- [Gumroad](https://gumroad.com/discover) - search for Blender (mostly non-free)

Answer (score 19):

## Documentation

- [Blender Manual](http://blender.org/manual/)
- [Blender Wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/)
- [Python API](http://www.blender.org/documentation/250PythonDoc/)

Answer (score 18):

### Free Online Courses

- [High school level course by James Chronister of Central Dauphin High School, Harrisburg, PA USA](http://www.cdschools.org/Page/455) about Blender 2.78

**Video Tutorials**

- [Blender Institute Channel on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/user/BlenderFoundation)
- [Blender Video Editing (2.7X series [Current Series])](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjyuVPBuorqIhlqZtoIvnAVQ3x18sNev4) by Mikeycal Meyers
- [Track, Match, Blend!](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLtuvwW4VAp5tu2RdbRHThM6FVFfvFur1g) by Sebastian König
- [Blender Character Creation Series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLyelx0TsmSpf-8xZfjZveokSsIwj0F3lo) by Darrin Lile
- [Blender 2.8 Beginner Tutorial Series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrjIgEdKLivgpCMmFC0_sV60Y_Ftp-WLD) by CG Geek
- [Blender 3.0 Beginner Donut Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjEaoINr3zgFX8ZsChQVQsuDSjEqdWMAD) by Blender Guru (Andrew Price)

Answer (score 17):

### Blogs

- [Ben Simonds](http://bensimonds.com/)
- [Greg Zaal](http://adaptivesamples.com)
- [Andrew Price](http://www.blenderguru.com/blog/)
- [Gleb Alexandrov](http://www.creativeshrimp.com/)
- [Samuel Sullins](https://blend.beehiiv.com)
- [Topology Guide](http://topologyguides.com/) (Good modelling practices)

---

### Communities and Forums

- [Official Blender site user community page](http://www.blender.org/support/user-community/)
- [Blender artists](http://www.blenderartists.org/)
- [Blender Cloud](https://cloud.blender.org/)
- [Blender Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/YourOwn3DSoftware/)(s)
- [Blender Stack Exchange](http://blender.stackexchange.com)
- [CG Cookie Community](http://community.cgcookie.com/c/blender)
- [Blender Nation](http://www.blendernation.com/)
- [Blender Discord OpenVFX](https://discord.com/invite/blender)
- [Blender Artists Group On LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/groups/6677523/)

Comment: I understand there are Facebook blender groups, but I deliberately don't facebook, so perhaps others will edit in links.

Comment: just have done so ;-)

Comment: Also added Google+ communities for us non-facebookers

Comment: What about Discord?

Answer (score 15):

### Sounds

#### Ambient and Songs

- [Soundcloud](https://soundcloud.com/) has many free downloadable audio tracks, the [terms of use](https://soundcloud.com/terms-of-use#grant-of-license) mention optional Creative Commons, but these files seem to be rare.
- [YouTube Audio Library](https://youtube.com/audiolibrary/music) contains Creative Commons and royalty-free music
- [INCOMPTECH](https://incompetech.com) Creative Commons music
- [CCMixter](http://dig.ccmixter.org/) Creative Commons music
- [PremiumBeat](https://www.premiumbeat.com) has fantastic high-quality music for a moderately low prices.

#### Sound Effects

- [Freesound](http://www.freesound.org/) Has a large collection of sound effects.
- [FreeSFX](http://www.freesfx.co.uk/) has a medium(ish) collection of free sounds. (Registration required)
- [YouTube Audio Library](https://www.youtube.com/audiolibrary/soundeffects) contains royalty-free sound effects

#### Game Sounds

- [sfxr](https://code.google.com/p/sfxr/downloads/list) Is a simple sound effect generator
- [Bfxr](http://www.bfxr.net/) Is is an elaboration of sfxr and has a web interface which allows download of created effect.
- [OpenGameArt.org](https://opengameart.org): sound effects, music, and more. Various licenses.

Comment: Don't think we should have screenshots for anything, unless we have screenshots for everything.

Comment: I agree, at least in this case.. I don't really see the point of this specific screenshot.

Answer (score 15):

### Themes

- [Contrib themes](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Interface/Themes/) (already included in non-release builds by default)
- [Blendswap](http://www.blendswap.com/terms/category/blender-themes)
- [BlenderArtists](http://blenderartists.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?48-Released-Scripts-and-Themes)

Answer (score 12):

## Books

NOTE: Check the [Blender Store](https://store.blender.org/product-category/books/) on the books listed below to see if they can be purchased through that facility; doing so helps support the Blender foundation.

### Beginner

- *[Beginners guide to cycles nodes, the procedural way](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zk2mWLxdRZmNLi6uww32LvGUJUQimrPFFKaoFbZ7_Jc)* Free online book in google docs.
- *[Blender 3D: Noob to Pro](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro)* Free online Wikibook, also available as a [pdf](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c1/BlenderDocumentation.pdf) or a 7zipped [html page](http://df.no-ip.info/pub/blender-wikibook-noob-to-pro-single-page.7z).
- *[Blender Foundations, The Essential Guide to Learning Blender 2.6](http://www.blenderfoundations.com/)* by Roland Hess. ISBN 978-0-240-81430-8. Version 2.6
- *[CRC Press, The Complete Guide to Blender Graphics: Computer Modeling & Animation, Third Edition](https://www.crcpress.com/The-Complete-Guide-to-Blender-Graphics-Computer-Modeling--Animation-Third/Blain/p/book/9781498746458)* by John M. Blain. ISBN 978-1-498-74645-8.

### Intermediate

- *[Mastering Blender](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118275403.html)* by Tony Mullen ISBN 978-1118275405
- *[Introducing Character Animation with Blender, 2nd Edition](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-047042737X,miniSiteCd-SYBEX.html)* by Tony Mullen. 978-0470427378
- *[Blender Master Class: A Hands-On Guide to Modeling, Sculpting, Materials, and Rendering](http://www.nostarch.com/blendermasterclass.htm)* by Ben Simonds ISBN 978-1593274771
- *[The Cycles Encyclopedia](http://www.blenderdiplom.com/en/shop/576-the-cycles-encyclopedia.html)* by Frederick Steinmetz and [Gottfried Hofmann](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/3484)

### Advanced

- *[Bounce, Tumble and Splash](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470192801.html)* by Tony Mullen ISBN 978-0-470-19280-1 (Physics Simulation) 2008

Comment: I miss a book which concentrates entirely on animation, especially animating characters, not for beginners but for advanced topics, like building a good posing library.

Comment: It's hard enough to find a book that focuses on animation for begginners.

Comment: i do agree that intermediate books are far to rare.

Answer (score 12):

### Blueprints

- [Car blueprints](http://carblueprints.info/eng/marks/)
- [The blueprints](http://www.the-blueprints.com/)
- [Blueprints Database](http://drawingdatabase.com/)

Answer (score 10):

## Integration with GIS (Geographic Information Systems (GIS))

There is no direct support for GIS in Blender, but there are a few addons to work with GIS data:

1) https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS (Shapefile and georeferenced raster files)

2) https://github.com/vvoovv/blender-geo (OpenStreetMap, SRTM, GPX).

Also read [here](https://github.com/vvoovv/blender-geo/wiki/Georeferenced-Blender-Scene) how georeferencing can be introduced to Blender.

Answer (score 9):

**Background Mathematics**

Linear Algebra

- Khan Academy: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra

Animation

- Skinning: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VdIjYevYuKk
- Curves / Interpolation: https://www.khanacademy.org/partner-content/pixar/animate#parametric-curves

Raytracing

- Collection of resources: http://www.realtimerendering.com/raytracing.html

Physical Simulation

- 3 different versions of a physics based animation course. Each course has a couple of different bits so they are all useful: https://www.youtube.com/user/kavanl1/playlists

Comment: This is currently just a quick list that I put together off the top of my head as a response to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135287/are-there-any-resources-for-learning-cg-related-math-especially-the-math-used-b, hopefully people can make this a bit better.

Comment: There needs to be a scripting category.

Answer (score 8):

### Fonts

- [FontSpace](http://www.fontspace.com/)
- [DaFont](http://www.dafont.com/)
- [Fonts.com](https://www.fonts.com/) (Paying)
- [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts)
- [1001 Fonts](http://www.1001fonts.com/)
- [Fontsquirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/)

Answer (score 0):

### Gometry Nodes and Simulation Nodes

- Erindale's geometry nodes tutorials on Youtube https://www.youtube.com/@Erindale
- Entagma's Blender Geometry Nodes Playlist https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPc8tXZv20w&list=PLdFfFRXT0K_hMTsT00-Oxe95V9-u3mwiv
- Default Cube Geometry nodes beginner tutorial for an abstract cube landscape https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmlpmHAa3vs
- Blender Guru's beginner Donut tutorial including geometry nodes https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nIoXOplUvAw